# "x" is read-only, but it isn't

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx

I have a Angular 10 (Typescript 3.9) project with the following class:

```
export class Document {
    constructor(
        public id: number,
        ...
        public tags: Tag[]
    ) {
        this.id = id;
        ...
        this.tags = tags;
    }
}
```

If I try to change tags (reassign or push) with

> document.tags = ...

for example in an existing object, I get:

> ERROR TypeError: "tags" is read-only

If I had a

> read-only

I would expect this behavior. Do you have any idea where this error comes from?

I recently upgraded from Angular 7 to 10, before that everything worked fine, but the upgrade instructions mentioned nothing about such behavior.

Deactivating strict-mode (even though considered bad practice) didn't work.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Please show where and how you create the `document` you're using in that code. (Be mindful of the fact there's a global called `document`. Could you be using that by mistake?)

Comment: [Works for  me](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCpwObIN4ChkHIhwC2EAXMgM5hSgYDcuAvrrhAB4AOA9lGMgQAbOFSrIAIjwQBXMuBz5CCHiBpQZCMHwAUSwoS4yARkOAJkwACaUQc49AA0+g8gD0b5ADofLg0dNzZDBMKkp0DABtAF0XAEpFV0IwAAtgKi9rZABeSysmJIIPb19C4LSMkIxxXKqqAsJWVlwVNQEraTkIBVyQCAB3SU75MB0AFgAmR2RI7GIySgAiGB4eReZouKYO2RGvOpyZudIKZEXjOCh16IYgA). Please update your question with a [mcve] showing the problem, ideally with a Playground link (as an *adjunct*) where we can see it run. (Side note: I'd probl pick a different name since `Document` is a predefined one. But shadowing it does work..)

Comment: Full sample? How do you import and instantiate the class, etc.

Comment: The documents (actually the class is called RecordDocument (I thought it would be easier without the full dependency) are passed down as Inputs and the single document is a Input too. 
How I create it in the end: `this.record_documents = Object.values(special_record.record_documents);`; special_record is from a subscription from ngrx.

Comment: I'il try to get a working example on Stackblitz.

Comment: Are you using a store in your project? Trying to change stored objects can lead to such effects, since the store creates readonly fields to make sure the state is not changed from outside the reducer.

Comment: Yes, I do use a store. I have subscribed to the object from the store and use it to pass down the (record-)documents.
But was there a change in ngrx? I didn't see this error before.

Comment: Yes, pre Angular most people additionally installed `ngrx-store-freeze` to retrieve the safety. With Angular 8 this feature was built in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer as per comments.

Changing ngrx stored objects can lead to such behavior, since the store guards the objects to be altered from outside the reducer.

Pre Angular 8 most people additionally installed `ngrx-store-freeze` to retrieve the safety. With Angular 8 the feature became built in.

You could try to disable it by setting `strictStateImmutability` to `false`, but it is not recommended to do so, because the store can now include unpredictable changes.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, {
      runtimeChecks: {
        strictStateImmutability: false,
      },
    }),
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Another option is to spread/copy all objects retrieved from the store before mutating them.

Answer (score 0):

First of all Document is reserved, try not to use it. and check the example below

```
class Tst {
    constructor(
        public id: number,
        public tags: number[]
    ) {
        this.id = id;
        this.tags = tags;
    }
}

var x = new Tst(1, [1,2])
x.id = 12
x.tags = [3,4]
```

Comment: You can (but shouldn't) shadow `Document`, so the name isn't the problem.